# How do I write a formula in excel that lists a value contained in one cell for each incremental number value contained in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a cell that contains csv data (Cell A). I have another cell that contains a quantity value (Cell B). I would like a formula that lists the Cell A for each incremental value contained in Cell B.

I have tried searching for related topics with no similar results.

An example of how I would like it to function:

```
Cell A is DataCell 
B is 5,
Column C:C (Formula) is Data,
spill into next row in C:C is Data,
spill into next row in C:C is Data,
spill into next row in C:C is Data,
spill into next row in C:C is Data
```

Comment: Are you describing `TEXTSPLIT()`? Do you have some sample data to clarify?

Comment: Dummy data and expected result would be appreciated

Comment: I don't believe it would be TEXTSPLIT().

Comment: I think my statement example above got confused.

Cell A would contain a CSV string. Cell B would contain a numerical value; 5. 
I am looking for a formula that lists the CSV string 5 times in column C.

Export should look like this:
Pear;Green;4;Low;
Pear;Green;4;Low;
Pear;Green;4;Low;
Pear;Green;4;Low;
Pear;Green;4;Low;

Comment: Apparently, I am not familiar enough with how comments output on this site. I am intending there to be line breaks after each string repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think I understand what it is you are after. You wish to repeat a certain value n-times in seperate cells. The fact that it's a CSV-value is irrelevant here.

[image]

Formula in `C1`:

```
=INDEX(A1,SEQUENCE(B1,,,0))
```

Or better:

```
=EXPAND(A1,5,,A1)
```

Comment: Your second option worked very well for me. My employer has a machine that takes CSV files in to generate a work order. I already have the CSV complier working but was running into difficulties figuring out how to tie a repeat counter to generate X copies of work orders.

I even tried out JSmart523's most recent clarifications, but liked the condensed formatting that the EXPAND() function provided.

My first choice was to write this is Python, an obviously better option than Excel, but Python is not allowed.

Thanks for the help and suggestions. I really appreciate the help and patience.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it separated by newline character in the same row, then for C2 the formula would be

```
=IF(
  OR(
    A2 = "",
    B2 = "",
    B2 < 1
  ),
  "",
  A2 & IF(
    B2 < 2,
    "",
    REPT(
      CHAR(10) & A2,
      B2 - 1
    )
  )
)
```

If instead you want C2 to spill down, you can convert it into an array using TEXTSPLIT like @JrdV suggested, with an empty 2nd argument and using the 3rd argument to split into rows.  So...

```
=IF(
  OR(
    A2 = "",
    B2 = "",
    B2 < 1
  ),
  "",
  TEXTSPLIT(
    A2 & IF(
      B2 < 2,
      "",
      REPT(
        CHAR(10) & A2,
        B2 - 1
      )
    ),
    ,
    CHAR(10)
  )
)
```

This assumes A2 doesn't contain any newline characters. If it does then you would have to use a delimiter other than CHAR(10), Perhaps "ç" or "§".

Comment: I tried both logics out, both with varying results.

In using the second recommendation, I am able to get the string to list. However, the issue I am having with it is that the final list gives me the ideal format, but the priors are repeating double within the same row.

String = Hello World;Mylar_CSV;Low;C:\Kit Cut\Projects\Tester;HelloWorld(Test);Mylar;_PARTNAME: HELLO WORLD!!_;

Set/Repetition = 5

Formula:
=IF(
   OR(
        A2 = "",
        B2 = "",
        B2 < 1
   ),
   "",
   A2) & IF(
B2<2,"",TEXTSPLIT(REPT(A2,B2-1),,"_"&";"))

Comment: Good catch. I've fixed the second solution. (`A2 & IF(...` needed to be moved inside of `TEXTSPLIT`)